# Emailing from webpage with PHP

Tags: php, email

I'm pretty new to PHP. I need to send an email from a webpage and thought that my code was good, but it's not sending anything. I can't see what i am doing wrong...

```
<?php
echo ("Thank you.")
$msg = "Some email message for testing. Please disregard if you receive this in your email.";
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
mail("email1@internet.com","Subject Verbiage",$msg);
mail("email2@internet.com","Subject Verbiage",$msg);
?>
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Please don't try to use php mail functions on your own. Use a library like swiftmailer. It will make your headers rich, as well as encrypt and allow complex emails such as using domain keys.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, i appreciate it.
I'm just trying to send a simple email when people land on a particular webpage...and am not sure what's wrong with my code. I've even looked at the php.ini and it looks like it should work.

Comment: Solved the problem...i neglected to put in the 'sent from' field. So the fixed mail line is...

mail("email@internet.com","Subject Verbiage","An email test message", "website@internet.com");